# Web Browser Kiosk - Recover From Network Outage

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, kiosk

I am running Firefox as a non-interactive kiosk type application that iterates through several web pages on different sites. For implementation, I have a page that uses JavaScript to iterate through an array of location.hrefs.

I want my kiosk page to be able to auto-recover when there is a network outage between my kiosk application and my web server. Currently, the application has to be restarted if there is an outage. Is there any way to implement this in ANY browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends. If the application is non-interactive it should be pretty simple. Just use two frames, load your application in one and have it change the URL in the other frame periodically. This way, the first frame never refreshes, so in case of a network outage it will keep cycling through the pages (although they will appear as errors) until the network is back (at which point the app will be back to normal on the next refresh).

Note that you don't have to **show** two frames. The first frame that only contains the required JavaScript to cycle through your pages can easily be invisible.

You could probably do more complicated stuff, such as polling with Ajax before a page change to see if you have a connection, but it's up to you to decide whether that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Set your page as home page and add Firefox to the Autostart folder.

For the kiosk mode, I found [an addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/full-fullscreen/) that claims to be helpful of this. Haven't tested it myself though...

**EDIT**  (Thought it was your site that should restart)
For the problem with sites in your switcher that stops responding I would do something like doing an ajax call to the page first and checking the http status. If it's ok - load the page in the content area (iframe?), if not, move on to the next page. The pages will be checked every time in the loop, which means a down page will be displayed when it comes back up.

Quite sketchy, but I hope you get the point?

Comment: Autostart is great but that won't help the browser recover from a failed network connection to a web page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar setup. I used Tab slideshow ( https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/tab-slideshow/ ) in combination with ScrollyFox ( https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/scrollyfox/ )

I have Slideshow setup so that it reloads the tabs every 30 second or so. I have one tab for each site that I want to demonstrate, and tab slideshow will cycle through them at a certain interval. Upside with this approach is that they will usually be fully loaded all the time.

For fullscreen in firefox 4, just F11 and then Alt + F4 and it will start up in full screen the next time it will load. I used Full Fullscreen for this before, but it hasn't been upgraded to support FF4 yet. It works in 3.6 though.